# Windows Task Scheduler trigger edit ignored

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-tasks

I have a task that has been running for years at 5:45 AM.  Recently we decided that running at 1:30 AM and repeating hourly for 12 hours is a better solution, so we made that change.  However, the following morning, the task was triggered at 5:45 AM anyway.  The change to the trigger seemed to have no effect, except that the task DID repeat once about an hour later.

This seems like a basic bug to me.  How is it possible that the trigger is fully ignored and the previous trigger is observed?  It has been running this way for 3 days now.

**Edit**

Trigger settings:
[image]

Event log
[image]

Comment: Hi, what does the Task Scheduler log days? Can you copy it? Also, did you update the user password?

Comment: Updated.  The manager has everything under his profile, he had to re-enter his credentials to make the change.  He did not update his password this time, but we have to do so periodically as part of internal security protocol.

Comment: I ran manually a couple of times, so I marked those in green as I don't want to confuse the issue.